# how to display Custom attribute admin in product grid in magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

I have created a custom attribute cms_pid. Now I want to show the value of the attribute in my magento admin product grid. how can I achieves this?

Answer (score 1):

There is already one flexible module in github for managing grid columns of any entities(orders, products, customers etc.):

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/GridControl

Answer (score 0):

Copy `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php`

and paste `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php`

and in the `Grid.php` file `_prepareCollection` method add your attribute

just like below

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('cms_pid');
```

and in `_prepareColumns` method add your feild just like below

```
   $this->addColumn('cms_pid',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('CMS  Pid'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'index' => 'cms_pid',
    ));
```

Comment: I have added a custom attribute(Name: Warehouse, along with three values) on my sales order grid. if order placed I need able to edit that attribute values, like eg. this order assigned for this warehouse like that. is possible can i edit what i need?   source : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/196004/57334

Answer (score 0):

We use this one as we can add custom attributes and also edit product attributes directly on the grid.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-grids-editor.html